# How to get from Orion all subscriptions inserted by owners

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

I need to filter subscriptions through logged users (i.e. user_id or organization_id) in a generic context.
The requirements are that any users can manage (edit or delete) only own subscriptions.
As far as I know, there isn't APIs to filter subscriptions by userid, so how can get from orion all subscriptions inserted by owners?

Comment: It's an interesting question. In my opinion we can use a new optional header (i.e. fiware-owner) like fiware-service and fiware-servicepath, to add info of owner (userid or organizationid). So, you can filter all calls on v2/subscription using that header if it exists. If you don't use fiware-owner, you can get all subscription without filter (normal execution).

Comment: This is a good and clear solution

Comment: Anyway, could I know if you foresee a solution to solve this task before to implement my workaround? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Orion doesn't support the ownership concept in subscriptions. A possible workaround could be to use some descriptive field (in particular, the `description` field) and a PEP-like proxy using that information to implement a mechanism like the one you want.

- At subscription creation time the proxy set the `description` to the user issuing the creation request.
- At subscription modification time, the proxy check if the user issuing the update request matches the one in the description.
- The proxy should forbid any attempt of setting/modifying the `description` field.

Not perfect, but may suffice your case. A proxy like that shouldn't be complex to implement in technologies like Nodejs.

Comment: I understand your point but I'm not fully sure if Orion should cope with that. According to the separation of concerns used by FIWARE global architecture, security aspects (including authentication and authorization, which are very closed to the concept of ownership) are in charge of the security framework (composed by a trio of GEs: PEP, AC an IDM). Need to be though with care. Maybe a new issue in Orion repository (something like "Implementing ownership in Orion") could be useful to drive the discussion and should be created there.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Probably I have to use the description field for other goal.

Comment: Another workaround can be to store in the database the user_id and the subscription_id, and before to show the list, to filter by user_id.

Comment: I prefer my solution, but If you want to use the description field as suggested by fgalan, you can use a prefix-postfix for description: i.e. USER_ID-xxxx-END where xxxx rapresents the id. Please take care of the description's size

Comment: Why not using notification metadata to store the user? Adding a "metadata" field in the notification body is possible, although it seems to be an undocumented feature.

Comment: That feature is documented in the NGSIv2 API spec at http://telefonicaid.github.io/fiware-orion/api/v2/stable/ in the "Subscriptions". Look for `metadata` field there.